# WordPress function.php changes automatically

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

A few days ago I added some custom functions to the function.php of my WordPress, yesterday also I did some changes to my function.php but today in the morning all of my custom functions were missing. On checking the modified date of the file it's showing as 10:56 pm. What could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

A wordpress theme update possibly happened?   If you wish to avoid any changes being overwritten when an update is processed, then create a child theme with a unque name, or use a site specific plugin.    Some help here: 
http://ottopress.com/2011/creating-a-site-specific-snippets-plugin/  or
https://ryanbenhase.com/write-site-specific-plugins-wordpress-site/